# Should I put tracking/analytical JS codes after the opening <body> tag or before the closing <body> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, analytics

Sometimes I was told the analytical codes should be put immediately after the opening `<body>` tag, while sometimes I was told the code snippet should be put before the closing `<body>` tag.

Does anyone have ideas about what is the main difference between these two approaches?  Which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, [Google says](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en):

> Paste your snippet (unaltered, in its entirety) into every web page you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing `</head>` tag.

Before, it was good to put it just before closing the `<body>` tag, because the script blocked the page loading. But now, it has the `async` attribute, so it doesn't really matter, but putting in the `head` tag will guarantee that anyone who actually has seen your page will be counted.